# Angular Google Maps custom zoom icons

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using AGM (Angular 6) and I can't figure out a way to change zoom in/out icons to custom ones. 
The AGM itself doesn't have such option, should it be done with pure JS? If so, how to do it best, as controls have no id or other kind of identification?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about overriding google maps controls, think about creating your own and sticking them on the map in the positions mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls

Docs are pretty self explanatory. Got the example from there and modified the bottom so you get the idea

```
      function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {

        // Set CSS for the control border.
        var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
        controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
        controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
        controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
        controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
        controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
        controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
        controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

        // Set CSS for the control interior.
        var controlText = document.createElement('div');
        controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
        controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
        controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
        controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
        controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
        controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
        controlText.innerHTML = 'Center Map';
        controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

        // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
        controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {

          map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1 )
          //you would create another div for zoom -1 and call the function from there
          }
      }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. However, I don't know how to connect all of that with AGM. for controlDiv I create a new div in template.html, but how can I get the 'map' object from AGM?

Comment: https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#info

Should be agm-map according to the docs.